# Get filepath of XSLT stylesheet in embedded C# code? (MSXML)

Tags: c#, xslt, visual-studio-2013, xslt-1.0, msxml

I use XSLT + C# code like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:local="urn:local"
                extension-element-prefixes="msxsl"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl local">

  <msxsl:script language="CSharp" implements-prefix="local">
    <![CDATA[
      public string imageList;

      public bool loadImageList()
      {
        imageList = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\me\\Project\\images.txt");
        return true;
      }

      public bool inImageList(string str)
      {
        return imageList.Contains("\r\n" + str + "\r\n");
      }
    ]]>
  </msxsl:script>

  <xsl:variable name="loadImageList" select="local:loadImageList()"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="recordList/record"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="record">
    <xsl:if test="inImageList(@id) = true()">
      <image>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@id, '.jpg')"/>
      </image>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In C#, an external file is loaded and the contents are stored in a variable. A function `inImageList()` provides the means to test, if a certain value is contained in that text. It is called by the XSLT code for conditional code execution (works).

My question: instead of hard-coding the file path `C:\\Users\\me\\Project\\images.txt`, I would like to provide a path / file name **relative to the .xslt file**. `.\\images.txt` does not work, it looks in some Visual Studio directory.

Is there a function, system-property or any other way to find out the absolute path to the my .xslt file?

Comment: Well, how do you load and execute the XSLT file? Can you show us your code doing that?

Comment: Good point! I'm executing the XSLT stylesheet in the VS user interface. So I simply load the .xslt file and click `Start XSLT Without Debugging` (it prompts which input XML is supposed to be used). There is no code that invokes the transformation. (I keep changing code, re-run the stylesheet and inspect the result directly in VS.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the stylesheet is loadable in a way that a base URI is available you could do it as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl mf"
                xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="mf">
    public string GetBaseUri(XPathNavigator node) {
      return node.BaseURI;
    }

    public string GetFilePath(string baseUri, string fileName) {
      return new Uri(new Uri(baseUri), fileName).LocalPath;
    }
  </msxsl:script>


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="mf:GetFilePath(mf:GetBaseUri(document('')), 'textInput.txt')"/>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this requires both enabling of script as well as of the `document` function, then inside of XSLT `document('')` can be used to get a tree representation of the stylesheet, you can then pass that to an extension function taking an `XPathNavigator` which allows you to read out the `BaseURI` property, once you have that, you can use the `Uri` class to resolve a file name relative to that base URI and you can then get a `LocalPath` representation of that URI, which you could then use to load the text file.

So in the context of your code you could use

```
  public bool loadImageList(string baseUri)
  {
    imageList = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(GetFilePath(baseUri, "images.txt"));
    return true;
  }

  public bool inImageList(string str)
  {
    return imageList.Contains("\r\n" + str + "\r\n");
  }

    public string GetBaseUri(XPathNavigator node) {
      return node.BaseURI;
    }

    public string GetFilePath(string baseUri, string fileName) {
      return new Uri(new Uri(baseUri), fileName).LocalPath;
    }
]]>
```

```
 <xsl:variable name="loadImageList" select="local:loadImageList(local:GetBaseUri(document('')))"/>
```

Comment: This is definitely the answer.

Comment: Tested and working, thank you! BTW: `GetBaseUri(...)` returns something like `file:///C:/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/stylesheet.xslt` and `GetFilePath(...)` returns `C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\stylesheet.xslt`.

Comment: @CoDEmanX, in the XML and XSLT world it is usually URI you can pass to APIs but I am not sure `ReadAllText` will support a URI so it seemed safer to provide or at least show a way to get a Windows file path from a URI.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case an XSLT fragment does not need to have a specific location. While it can be stored in a file, it could also be a network stream, it could be embedded in an XML document and so forth. So in XSLT there is no concept of "my own location" which you could query.

However, since I assume that you use the `XslCompiledTransform` class to perform the transformation, you could inject a parameter there (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addparam(v=vs.110).aspx) for details) and pass it to your `loadImageList` function.

Comment: I do not use XSLT in C#, but C# in XSLT, thus there is no `XslCompiledTransform` class or similar. But thanks for your answer!